# What do the posts with different backgound color mean?

Tags: support

Recently, I was browsing English Language Learners' posts. I found on some posts, the background color is a bit different, some are light yellow, most are white.

I would like to know what is the meaning of these posts with different background colors?

[image: Screenshot showing highlighted question]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can "favorite" a tag, in which case questions with that tag will be highlighted in yellow.  You can also "ignore" a tag, in which case questions with that tag will be dimmed or not displayed at all, depending on your settings.

You can edit your list of favorited/ignored tags by going to your profile, then clicking "Edit Profile & Settings", and then clicking the "Preferences" tab:

> [image: screen shot of preferences page]

That's also where you can choose whether you want to hide questions with ignored tags, or just make them fade out a bit.

Alternatively, you can favorite or ignore a tag by clicking the little star that shows up under a tag when you move your mouse over it:

> [image: screen shot of mouse over]

Personally, I discovered this yellow highlighting thing when I clicked a star accidentally.  I didn't even realize I'd done it the first time, so I thought something had changed on Stack Exchange without my doing anything, and I was really confused by the yellow highlighting.  So if you don't know why you're getting yellow highlighting right now, I'm guessing you might have accidentally done the same thing :-)

For more information, please see [**How do I find topics I'm interested in?**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) in the Help Center.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation in detail. really helpful for me.  Thanks.